# Link to directory on website but prevent direct downloads

Tags: html, web, download

I have searched but not yet come across any real solution...I've got a store on one of my sites where I'd like to sell some of my own music via mp3 download. The download part is just fine and there's no problem with actually selling the files. But since they're music files, I really wanted to have a streaming version available so that people can hear the song before they buy it.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to offer a preview without allowing web savvy people to just view the source code, follow the link directly to the file and download it from there. Locking/password protecting the directory doesn't work since then people are prompted for login info when they click the play button on the site.

It seems like a contradiction so maybe it's just not doable, but is there a way to either allow the link to be used on the site but not allow it to be downloaded if someone tries to access the full path in their own browser? Or is there a way to mask the link being used? I've seen this question around a lot but I haven't seen a useable answer yet. The alternative would be to upload a short clip of the song for preview purposes but that's quite a bit of extra work and I was hoping to allow visitors to hear the whole song online if they wanted to.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, anything that can be played can also be recorded.  There is absolutely no way around this fact, so set your expectations accordingly.

For your purposes, there are some common techniques, both technical and simply practical:

- Your preview clips should not be the whole song.  Try a 1-minute clip.
- Consider audibly water-marking if you must include an entire song.  Either fading in, recording someone saying, "this is a preview", or similar.
- Serve your download links dynamically.  A link to the media should only be usable by the person with a session on your site.  When a file is requested, make it accessible via a token that only works with that person's session ID.  This prevents someone sharing a link directly with others.

Comment: Thanks, as I said, the actual selling of mp3s isn't a problem. I'm using a pay per download plugin with short term links sent to the person upon completing their payment. It was the preview issue that my question was about and, from your answer, it looks like that's not going to be possible. So I guess I'll just have to go with the short clip for preview purposes! Thanks for your help :o)

Answer (score 0):

i have never found a site wich offer music through some kind of js/html audio player, where you cannot download the file.

what i have seen is very low quality samples, cuted in half,1 min, etc versions, urls ofuscated on javascript variables or asked dinamically with ajax, to at least avoid direct linking on the source.

And, maybe what you are looking for, some kinds of streaming through flash based audio players. maybe its also possible with java.

greetings!